# Map data with gradient colors not showing correctly online, but works fine in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, arcgis-online

My map with gradient color symbology looks/acts correctly in ArcGIS Pro. When I successfully upload it into ArcGIS Online, the colors no longer match up with the data. I think this has something to do with the fact that the data is a one-to-many relationship for the 50 US States (multiple data points for each state over time): I think ArcGIS Online is not reading the polygon boundaries correctly because there are overlapping, existing polygons for each state(for example: Each row of data for Alabama contains the same polygon column information). Is there a way for me to display this correctly on ArcGIS Online?

Answer (score 1):

To get the desired output we need to have the table in ArcGIS online, and the workflow is given below:-

1. Create a relationship class between the feature class and the table based on the Global ID and GUID fields.
2. Publish the feature class and the related table to ArcGIS Online as a hosted feature layer.
3. Open the hosted feature layer in ArcGIS Online Map Viewer, and join the related table with the feature layer.

   a) In ArcGIS Online Map Viewer, **click the Analysis tab**, and navigate to **Summarize Data > Join Features.**

   b) In the **Join Features pane**, select the feature layer for **Choose target layer**.

   c) For Choose layer to join to target layer, **select the related table**.

   d) For **Select the type(s) of joins**, click Choose the **fields to match** and **select the Global ID and GUID fields**.

   e) Select the join operation type, and specify a name for the Result layer name.

   f) Click **RUN ANALYSIS** to perform the join. A new, joined feature layer containing the related table values is added to the Contents pane.
4. Symbolize the joined feature layer with values from the related table.

   a) On the **Details** tab, click **Content** to view the layers in the Contents pane.

   b) Hover over the joined feature layer, and click Change Style.

   c) In the **Change Style** pane, for Choose an attribute to show, select the desired fields from the related table to symbolize the layer.

   d) For Select a drawing style, select Types (Unique Symbols), and click OPTIONS to configure the symbol.

   e) **Click OK**, and click DONE to apply the symbol. The layer is symbolized with values from the related table.

Comment: Would you mind clarifying more about creating a relationship class between the feature class and the table based on the Global ID and GUID fields? I established a one-to-many relationship in the ArcGIS Online join. After I did the online join, each row was assigned a unique Object ID- is this not enough? I also noticed after the online Join that all of my dates are now off. Thank you.

Comment: https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000015422, this is for use in ArcGIS Collector, you can follow the exact workflow.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance- I'm beginning to understand the problem better! I followed the tutorial and then executed the ArcGIS Online join, but am still ending up with only the 50 rows of data from my original target layer. I have 1006 total rows from the related table that should have been added. Any suggestions? There seems to be an issue with the one-to-many relationship.